# How do I get my computer name to show correctly in the finder?

Tags: bonjour, macos

I recently upgraded to Yosemite and following that upgraded to an SSD drive. Life is good and I am happy with everything except that since the upgrades I am seeing a silly variety of names for my computer.

I renamed it to The Shire and now it shows up as The Shire(2) or The Shire(3). No matter how many times I change it back in Preferences > Sharing, it keeps adding all those extra numbers. There are times when I see four or five different iterations of my system - see attached image.

[image]

To add insult to injury, the old name of my system, the generic MacBook Pro (5) also shows in the list.

From what I have read this may have something to do with Bonjour, but I have not see any solutions out there for restoring order and correct names to list.

Sage advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this annoying bug by unchecking 'Back to my Mac' and 'Find my Mac' in System Preferences/iCloud.

Comment: Alas doesn't work for me.

Comment: I believe this is a Yosemite bug. Hopefully, it will get fixed in the 10.10.1 or 2 release.